# What's the fastest way to manipulate a multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, multi-index

I want to manipulate a multiindex dataframe, but I find it much lower than the single index dataframe (with essentially the same function).

For example, we create a dataframe of the shape 30*30. And stack it to get a multiindex dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 30
groupA = [f'A{_}' for _ in range(n)]
groupB = [f'B{_}' for _ in range(n)]
single = pd.DataFrame(np.array([_ for _ in range(n*n)]).reshape((n, n)), columns=groupB, index=groupA)
multi = single.stack().to_frame()
multi.columns = ['item']
```

To show my point, let's shift the single-index dataframe to right by one step, and add Nan to fill the void.

```
def func(row):
    row = np.concatenate(([np.nan], row.values[:-1]))
    return row
    
%timeit -n 100 single_shift = single.apply(func, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Timeit result is:

> 2.52 ms ± 228 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Shifted dataframe:
[image: Shifted single index dataframe]

But if we do the same thing with multiindex dataframe, it's 20 times slower.
Like this:

```
def shift(multi):
    for ai in multi.index.levels[0]:
        multi.loc[(ai, slice(None)), 'item'] = np.concatenate(([np.nan], multi.loc[(ai, slice(None)), 'item'].values[:-1]))
    return multi

%timeit -n 100 shift_multi = shift(multi)
```

Timeit result is:

> 46.2 ms ± 6.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Shifted multi-index dataframe:

[image: Shifted multi-index dataframe]
[image: Shifted multi-index dataframe2]

As we can see, it the same result with essentially the same action. But it take 20* times to do the same thing with multiindex. Is there a faster way to manipulate multiindex dataframe?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My hunch is that you'll find `DataFrame.shift` to be faster than your functions

Comment: yeah, `Dataframe.shift` is about 20x faster on my machine with your example

Comment: Thanks Paul. I can think it would be faster for single index case. But could you apply `Dataframe.shift` for multi-index dataframe? It's shift by different index of "groupB".

Comment: Yes, I would use shift for a MultiIndexed Dataframe. But I don't understand your last sentence or your expected results in the MultiIndex case

Comment: I mean, to shift multi-index dataframe just like single index, I cannot apply `multi.shift(1)`. It will shift the entire column with no breaks. My expectation is to shift each groupB seperately. The result is like this: every "B0" should all be Nan.

Comment: try something like `multi.groupby(level=0).shift()`

Comment: In either case, you only have to shift your `single` dataframe once, and you have to shift your `multi` dataframe, 30 times. So it sounds like `single.shift(axis=1).stack()` is the way to go

Comment: Thanks Paul. It's a good suggestion. But I have to perform in multi-index for some other reasons. `groupby` idea sounds better.

Comment: i'm not saying you ditch the multiindex -- I'm saying you do your data prep, then unstack+shift(axis=1) the dataframe, then re-stack, and continue on with your analysis chain